# Flutter test - Failure in method after 'All tests passed!'

Tags: flutter

I have a very basic Flutter test.  After a successful test (using ChromeDriver) called via below, a failure is encountered, possibly after the TearDown?

initiate test by: flutter drive \ --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart \ --target=integration_test/app_test.dart
\ -d edge

Test:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';

import 'package:rova/main.dart' as app;

void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  group('end-to-end test', () {
    testWidgets('Select the Submit Incident link, verify frame opens', (tester) async {

      //setup
      app.main();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      //do
      final Finder login = find.text('Login');
      await tester.tap(login);
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5)); //allow time for login to process
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      
      final Finder button = find.text('Submit Incident');
      await tester.tap(button);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      //test
      expect(find.text('INCIDENT SUBMISSION'),findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}
```

The test passes, however then comes up with a Failure:

```
Launching integration_test/app_test.dart on Edge in debug mode...
Asset manifest contains a null or empty uri.
Waiting for connection from debug service on Edge...               74.8s
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:62166/bV0WQwjk6d0=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62166/bV0WQwjk6d0=/ws
00:00 +0: end-to-end test Select the Submit Incident link, verify frame opens
00:13 +1: (tearDownAll)
00:13 +2: All tests passed!
Failure Details:
Failure in method: Select the Submit Incident link, verify frame opens
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞═════════════════
The following assertion was thrown running a test:
The finder "zero widgets with text "Submit Incident" (ignoring
offstage widgets)" (used in a call to "tap()") could not find any
matching widgets.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 288:49  throw_
packages/flutter_test/src/controller.dart 1293:7                              [_getElementPoint]
packages/flutter_test/src/controller.dart 1232:12                             getCenter
packages/flutter_test/src/controller.dart 554:18                              tap
app_test.dart 29:19                                                           <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1407:47                                          _rootRunUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1308:19                                          runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                    handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 784:44                                    handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 813:13                                    _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 584:5                                     [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 657:7                                     <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1399:13                                          _rootRun
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1301:19                                          run
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1209:7                                           runGuarded
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1249:23                                          callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 177:15           <fn>

The test description was:
  Select the Submit Incident link, verify frame opens
═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

end of failure 1
```

I cannot work out why it is passing then test, then seemingly failing.

Comment: What's the second test?

Comment: Your issue seems to be related to [integration_test package pauses isolates and calling pumpAndSettle() never finishes](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73355) and [integration_test ensureInitialized() inside setUpAll() fails, and tests hangs](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72063).
Can you try upgrading your flutter?

Comment: It's only one test.  As per the logs, after the test is advised as '00:13 +2: All tests passed!' it seemingly fails 'Failure in method: Select the Submit Incident link, verify frame opens'.  It is like it tries to executes 'await tester.tap(button);' again, after the test is finished?

Comment: Thanks @Mearaj - updated to 3.10.5, however still occurring.

Comment: @dogowar, it's difficult to say without the main.dart file. You can yourself try by temporary replacing real code with some dummy one, just for testing, in your main.dart file.